# An example of a span that is not a product.

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I'm trying to understand the difference of [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_(category_theory)) and [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)). So far every example of span I know of is also a product. E.g. Wikipedia has an example:

> - Any object yields the trivial span $A = A = A$; formally, the diagram $A ← A → A$, where the maps are the identity.

The example is also a product, by virtue of having an object $W=A$ with morphisms *(the identity)* to all three objects.

The only way for a span $X$ to not be a product seem to have an object $W$ with arrows to all objects of the diagram except of $X$. E.g.:

$$ \begin{array}{}
\begin{align} & \; W \\ 
\swarrow & \quad \searrow \\
X₁ ← & X → X₂ \end{align}
\end{array} $$

To me the diagram seem to be useless outside of category theory, because usually if the object $W$ has enough info to get to $X₁$ and $X₂$, it's also enough to get to $X$. But mathematicians wouldn't create a whole separate concept out of something extra rare, so there have to exist examples of spans that are not products. What are they?

Comment: **To future readers**: if you're wondering of the same question, the ["Crash Course in Category Theory" talk](https://youtu.be/JH_Ou17_zyU?t=2071) by Bartosz Milewski has a great illustrative answer at 34:31 *(except he doesn't explicitly says about spans)*. He compares a pair of α and β to a triple that also contains γ. While both the pair and the triple are spans, from his example it's clear that triple is not a product of α and β, but the pair is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Span is *any* diagram of shape $• ← • → •$ while product is a very special span – it is such span that any other span with the same end-objects uniquely factorizes through it. For example, the trivial span is almost never a product: $A × A$ is often a different object than $A$.

Comment: Thank you, I got the gist, but still, $A×A$ is both a span and a product *(as a special case of a span)*, and $A$ is both a span and a product too — it's the example from Wikipedia.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Where do you read that $A ← A → A$ is a product? (Since it is almost never true.)

Comment: Because there is a fourth object $A$ having arrows to all 3 you mentioned.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: What does that have to do with being a product?

Comment: It satisfies the universal property of products: for a diagram of the form $X₁←X→X₂$, and for every object $W$ such that $X₁←W→X₂$, if $W$ factorizes through $X$, i.e. $W → X$, then $X$ is a product.

Comment: There is *for every object $W$*, you just proved that for $W = A$. For $W = A × A$ it would be false. If $A$ is a two-point set, then it's product with itself is a four-point set, so $A$ as a two-point set is not a product.

Comment: Woah, I see, this is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Although I just thought a bit more of it… Let's imagine a category $SET$, there we have a diagram $A ← A →A$ *(i.e. a single object with identities)*, and $A←A×A→A$ *(a cartesian product of the object with itself)*. If I understand correctly, we would rather have a $A×A → A$ but not $A → A×A$. Hence from the POV of category theory a product is not $A×A$ but $A$. It sounds rational, but strange.

Comment: I don't think it's strange, the idea of product comes from Cartesian product. Also, $2 × 2 = 4$ and not $2$. Also note that $A \cong A × A$ for $A$ empty or one-point.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that idea of product comes from Cartesian product, and hence the example from my prev. comment the $A×A$ should be the product. But it's not!

Comment: No, it is. $A × A$ is the product, $A$ is not. I misread your previous post.

Comment: But we don't have an arrow $A → A×A$, do we? Hence, because there is $A←A→A$ and $A←A×A→A$, and $A×A → A$, i.e. $A×A$ factors through $A$, the product is $A$ but not $A×A$.

Comment: It's the other way. We have $A → A × A$, but not $A × A → A$ commuting with the diagram.